# Modifying WordPress Query --> Order By Custom Value In Another Table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sorting

I created a new additional table that ranks the posts similar to the one below:

```
------------------
| post_id | rank |
| 6       | 3    |
| 4       | 1    |
| 5       | 2    |
------------------
```

I'd like to sort the posts in my site's search results so that they're ordered by the ranks from this custom table. I would like to leverage WP's built in functions but is there a way to do that using `$query->set()`?

```
if ($query->is_search) {
    ...
    $query->set('orderby', ???);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to use the `posts_join` and `posts_orderby` filters.

So basically, join your new table on post_id and adjust the orderby.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby